# Outputting Jersey logging to a file?

Tags: java, logging, jersey

We've added these to our web.xml:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Which is nice for debugging in my dev environment, but, I can't see any examples on logging these things to files on our testing server! All I see is that the default is System.out... not how to pass in anything.

Examples would be nice! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, LoggingFilter logs to a JDK logger named as its fully qualified class name (com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter). You'll just have to

1. [configure JDK logging the usual way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/logging/overview.html#1.8) ,
2. [bridge it to your favorite logging framework](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j), or
3. [use whatever mechanism your application server may provide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html).