# Jersey Logging filter

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, log4j, jersey

I added Logging filter to my Jersey rest webservices client and I see all the Jersey logs being printed at catalina.out instead of my application specific log file. Sometimes, I also see the spring/jsp errors being printed at catalina.out instead of application log files.

I have the following for spring in my log4j.properties. Should I add somehting for Jersey too? I understand this is a log4j configuration question, would appreciate if somebody can respond.

```
 log4j.logger.org.springframework=warn
```

Answer (score 1):

Try as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760305/outputting-jersey-logging-to-a-file) if you need to redirect jersey logging to the file.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to set your logger level appropriately .

DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL

when the logger you use for logging is lower level , then the log falls to upper levels.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html

that may be the reason why your logs fall to top level